# How to add GraphView to a Listview?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-graphview

I want my app to add Graphs ( I'm using GraphView library to do it ) , conform a variable.

Like `if x=3` , then it will apear 3 graphics on the activity. `If x=10` it will be 10 graphics.

I think the `listview` would do it , but I just dont know how to implement it .

Comment: Where do you stuck?

Comment: I dont know even how to start. A perfect solution would be a loop like : while( x>0 ) { create a new graph ; x-- ); I want to generate widgets programmatically , I dont know if that's possible